# min height in min height css

Tags: internet-explorer, height, css

Im trying to have one div which has min height 100% and antoher within with min height 100% as well.

I am not allowed to touch the markup, it has to be done with pure css. It also must work in IE6+ so i cant use display:table.

How can i achieve this?

Currently i have html,body set to height:100%, wrapper set to min-height:100% but then the inner div needs the outer div to have a height setting in order to have a % setting itself...

What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you actually want to achieve. Please post the markup (because it is fixed and must be used as a base to work with), and an image of what you want to achieve (preferably with clear markings about where divs should start and end).

Comment: Why not just height instead of min-height?

Comment: @Sparky672 if you just use height, the div won't reflow as it would with min-height. Adjust the JS Fiddle I posted to see this issue in action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to support IE6, min-height is out of the picture.

You could use min-height in other browsers and add a conditional statement to set height rather than min-height in IE.

IE8 and above support min-height.

For the browser that do support min-height, you don't actually need to nest min-height declarations. You only need min-height on the outer element, the inner element uses height.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dmyN6/

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;   
}

.a {
    min-height: 100%;   
    background-color: blue;
}

.b {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: aqua;    
}
```

Comment: well im gonn use height instead of min-height in CC for IE6 so thats not gonna be a problem, my question is more if there is a way to have min height within min height

Comment: I have added an example - you don't need nested `min-height`. The elements auto grow with just the outer element using `min-height` and the inner element using `height`.

Comment: problem is, the inner div now stretches with more content but doesnt fill the outer div without content see my edit of the js fiddle to see what i mean, the aqua colored box should be as heigh as the outer one regardless of content http://jsfiddle.net/dmyN6/1/

Comment: How does this work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/dmyN6/3/ it has the min height switched to the inner div.

Comment: it overlaps with the outer div, but i guess it cant be done other wise. thx

Comment: I believe the only way (currently) to get perfectly aligned "min-heigh-esque" divs is with a JavaScript polyfill - but if you can live with just one of them having min-height and the other having height, you can avoid the script.